# Incorrect results from Thrust for custom functor run on host

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

i get bad results when i try to implement any functor. For example i tried a negate functor similar to `thrust::negate<T>`
Here is a sample code producing good results using build in negate functor:

```
int data[10] = {-5, 0, 2, -3, 2, 4, 0, -1, 2, 8};
int out[10];
thrust::negate<int> op;
thrust::transform(data, data + 10, out, op);
```

`out` variable becomes `{5, 0, -2, 3, -2, -4, 0, 1, -2, -8}`, but when i implemented my own functor like

```
struct NegateFunctor{
__host__ __device__
    int operator()(const int &val) const {
        return -val;
}
};
```

and call it as `thrust::transform(data, data + 10, out, NegateFunctor())` `out` contains `{-858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460, -858993460}`

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, 5.0 CUDA on a 64 bit machine.

Thanks

Comment: Your functor is fine, and I can compile and run a simple example using it which produces the expected results. Can you post the shortest possible complete example which demonstrates the problem? Otherwise it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: Hi talonmies, a short example is shown here [link](http://pastebin.com/PVWCkcT1). The file is compiled as CUDA C++ and has extension `.cu`. I'm including also the image of `out` variable [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/ihd.png/)

Comment: Your code works as expected for me. There isn't any error I can find. If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: I think i found a solution [link](http://pastebin.com/3zPURELC), but it isn't like all the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile and run your code (only modified to added printing of the result of the `thrust::transform` call):

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

struct NegateFunctor{
    __host__ __device__
        int operator()(const int &val) const {
            return -val;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int data[10] = {-5, 0, 2, -3, 2, 4, 0, -1, 2, 8};
    int out[10];
    //thrust::negate<int> op;
    thrust::transform(data, data + 10, out, NegateFunctor());
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << data[i] << " " << out[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this (CUDA 5.0 on OS 10.6.7):

```
$ nvcc thrust_neg2.cu 
$ ./a.out
-5 5
0 0
2 -2
-3 3
2 -2
4 -4
0 0
-1 1
2 -2
8 -8
```

Which appears to be correct. If you aren't seeing the same result, then either this is a specific issue with the toolchain you are using, or something else you haven't told us is causing the problem.

EDIT: And it appears from comments you are building with nvcc in debug mode, which is known not to work with Thrust. I would recommend only building code for release. If the problem persists, this should probably be a bug report to the Thrust developers, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: i don't use any specific setting for CUDA. The command line command is [link](http://pastebin.com/0LKusSwE). Inherited are `Optimization=/Od`, `Runtime Library = /MDd`, `Basic Runtime Checks = /RTC1`, `Enable Run-Time Type Info = `, `Warning Level = /W3` (but i thing all those values are default). I'm using Windown 8 x64. Thanks

Comment: But you do. You are building in debug mode, not release mode. Thrust is known to misbehave when built for debugging - see (here)[https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Debugging]. Build for release and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that about Thrust. Thank you!